# Internet Explorer 8 in Windows 7

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

guys!

I am working on a project, which has to have same (as possible) look in all major browsers. The client, however, thinks that IE 7 - 8 are major browsers so the site has to be compatible with them. On my laptop I have Windows 7 with pre-installed IE 9. How can I test my site if it works in IE 8 and lower? I tried the IE Tab plug-ins for Chrome and Firefox, but there are some major differences from the look in pure IE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open Internet Explorer and press F12.  This will open the Developer ToolBar.  At the top it has Browser Mode.  You can change the browser's rendering engine there.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't install multiple copies of IE on the same machine I'd recommend using virtual PCs.  This will guarantee an accurate test of your page in IE 7/8.  Microsoft provides a set of VHDs for this purpose http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11575.

Comment: I saw this in another post here, but these copies are 3GB only for IE.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package containing many different versions of IE. You can download it [here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Browsers/Internet-Explorer-Collection.shtml), maybe this will help you.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to install IE7 and IE8. I worked with it on my XP machine some time ago and I've been using it, but on Windows 7 it doesn't allow me to install IE7 and IE8. Thanks for the reply btw!